# sed command to filter only set of numbers followed by a comma

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a file that looks like this

```
0: jdbc:hive2://10.241.1.8:10000/> select number,exported_at from audit group by number,exported_at order by number limit 10;
789116704,20150907T130500Z
789190212,20150907T130500Z
789255093,20150907T130500Z
789282142,20150907T130500Z
789359510,20150907T130500Z
789363793,20150907T130500Z
789363843,20150907T130500Z
789369808,20150907T130500Z
789437014,20150907T130500Z
789437071,20150907T130500Z
0: jdbc:hive2://10.241.1.8:10000/>
```

I would like to keep only the line that has the numbers followed by a comma. i.e my output should look like this

```
    789116704,20150907T130500Z
    789190212,20150907T130500Z
    789255093,20150907T130500Z
    789282142,20150907T130500Z
    789359510,20150907T130500Z
    789363793,20150907T130500Z
    789363843,20150907T130500Z
    789369808,20150907T130500Z
    789437014,20150907T130500Z
    789437071,20150907T130500Z
```

I am looking for an sed command that can do this job. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E '[0-9]+,' data.txt
```

where data.txt is the file with your input data

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
sed -n '/[0-9],/p' file
```